# UITableViewCell - registerNib subclass not finding nib as subview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

In the viewDidLoad in my UITableView I am calling:

```
[self registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCellRI"];
```

Then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath I have the following:

```
MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellRI"];

[cell setup:[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Inside the setup method I have a look on [self subviews] to go through the subviews and assign content based on key/value but in this loop I find UITableViewCellContentView's but I do not see the my custom view defined in the NIB.

In the NIB I have assigned Files Owner & The custom class of my cell. The cell is showing I just can't find the NIB view in the subviews.

Please advise.

James

Comment: Are you sure the reuse identifier specified in the nib is the same as in your code?

Comment: Yes I have the reuse identifier set in the nib. In my subviews loop I get about 15 UITableViewCellContentView as the class when I do [subview class];

Comment: Maybe your xib file does not have UITableViewCell as the top-level object.

Comment: There is only 1 object in the XIB which is the UITableViewCell which has the subclass on it.

Comment: Also I can see the contents of the NIB so I know it is working just check I call [cell setup:] and loop through the contents I don't find that view that I can see on screen :(

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through subviews is hard work) Try to avoid it. it is not very good practice because it is not reliable. For instance if you decided to change your custom cell UI you will have to change method where you're iterating through subviews.

Try to do following:

Let's say that there is custom cell with UIImage and 3 strings (e.g. person's name, age and cell phone number)

Implement 3 functions in your custom cell to set this values as follows:

MyCustomCell.h
... .h file standart code and then at the end ...

```
@propert(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;
@propert(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *myFirstLabel;
@propert(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *mySecondLabel;
@propert(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *myThirdLabel;
- (void)setUIimage:(UIImage *)_image;
- (void)setFirstString:(NSString *)_string;
- (void)setSecondString:(NSString *)_string;
- (void)setThirdString:(NSString *)_string;
```

MyCustomCell.m:

```
@synthesize myImageView, myFirstLabel, mySecondLabel, myThirdLabel;

- (void)setUIimage:(UIImage *)_image {
    self.myImageView.image = _image;
}

- (void)setFirstString:(NSString *)_string {
    self.myFirstLabel.text = _string;
}

 - (void)setSecondString:(NSString *)_string {
    self.mySecondLabel.text = _string;
}

 - (void)setThirdString:(NSString *)_string {
    self.myThirdLabel.text = _string;
}
```

and finaly in your tableView controller cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
[myCustomCell setUiImage:someImage];
[myCustomCell setFirstString:oneString];
[myCustomCell setSecondString:twoString];
[myCustomCell setThirdString:threeString];
```

Hope this approach will help you. Feel free to ask if you have some questions

Comment: I do know this way to do it but I am trying to make more dynamic cells and setting the value of the cells via key/value pairs that are assigned in the NIB. I just don't know how to find the UILabels in the UITableCell subclass instead of just finding the UITableViewCellContentView.

Comment: You don't need to find them. Just add in your custom cell function which will take nsstring and set it to your label. What part of my answer was hard for you to understand? I will specify it